# How can I implement obj^-1 (1/obj) for my own class?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, methods

Does anybody know you to implement 1/obj for a class/an object that I implemented myself?

Is there any dunder method like __truediv__ for the case obj/(obj or number)?
Or do I need to override somehow the int class of python itself?

Context: I am programming just for fun my own complex numbers class and I need to be able to calculate 1/z.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well I already did that for the case "obj divided by another obj or number (int/float)" but now I'd like to implement the case "1/obj".
When I'm not getting something wrong the \_\_truediv\_\_ does not cover the case "1/obj".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the **dunder** method called `__pow__`. The signature is like this: `def __pow__(self, power, module=None)`.

A small example:

```py
class MyNumber:
    def __init__(self, value: float):
        self.value: float = value

    def __pow__(self, power, modulo=None):
        return self.__class__(self.value ** power)

    def __str__(self):  # just for using with print function
        return str(self.value)


num = MyNumber(5)
print(num ** 5)  # 3125
print(num ** -1)  # 0.2
```

The last expression `num ** -1` can be used for `1/obj`. Maybe you can check the power argument value within the method and decide to do something.

Comment: The \_\_pow\_\_ method is actually the reason why I'd like to find out whether there's way of implementing 1/obj:
For a negative power (e.g. -2), I first raise my obj to the power of 2 and then I want to check if the power is negative. If so, I'd like to simply compute 1/obj before returning the result. I know how I could work around this problem so that I would not have to implement 1/obj, but it would be nice if I could implement 1/obj in general so that you could use it without any problem e.g. in formulas or in the console and so on.

But I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: No problem. I hope you can find a good solution for your problem

Answer (score 0):

For `1 / obj` you can implement the special method `__rtruediv__` (look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) for more information):

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int | float):
            return MyClass(self.value / other)
        return MyClass(self.value / other.value)  # Otherwise
    
    def __rtruediv__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int | float):
            return MyClass(other / self.value)
        return other.__truediv__(self)  # Otherwise
```